# "hadoop dfs -cat output" returns nothing

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I implement the code in the site http://fiware-cosmos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_and_programmer_manual/batch/using_hadoop_and_ecosystem/#top which consists to add the parameter "regex" into the command line for MapReduce program.The program run very well it shows

```
16/06/28 17:19:47 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/06/28 17:19:47 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/06/28 17:19:48 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1448020964278_0633
16/06/28 17:19:49 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1448020964278_0633
16/06/28 17:19:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://co2-hdpmaster.irit.fr:8088/proxy/application_1448020964278_0633/
16/06/28 17:19:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1448020964278_0633
16/06/28 17:19:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1448020964278_0633 running in uber mode : false
16/06/28 17:19:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/06/28 17:20:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/28 17:20:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/06/28 17:20:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1448020964278_0633 completed successfully
16/06/28 17:20:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=6
                FILE: Number of bytes written=230845
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=916
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=6
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Rack-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=7478
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=7151
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7478
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=7151
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=7478
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=7151
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=22972416
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=21967872
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=17
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=6
                Input split bytes=125
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=6
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =1
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=1
                GC time elapsed (ms)=114
                CPU time spent (ms)=2120
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1398767616
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=6716833792
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2156396544
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=791
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
```

when I want to show the content of the file with the command `hadoop dfs -cat output/part-r-00000` it returns nothing 
Someone can explain the problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job didnt produce any results:

```
Map output records=0
Reduce output records=0
HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
```

So the files are probably empty. You should check their size on HDFS to confirm this.

Comment: you are right, the size is 0 bytes. but i don't understand why the file is empty.

Comment: Probably your "regex" pattern is filtering out all output records! You can check if after removing the regex, something is written.

Comment: I would just wildcard the regex so you match everything. Feel free to accept this answer if its correct.